# npgsql 2.1.3 and EF 6: Could not determine storage version; a valid storage connection or a version hint is required

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, npgsql

I'm adding the support to EF 6 to my sql generator for PostgreSQL: [PostgreSQL Migration Generator](https://github.com/darionato/PostgreSqlMigrationSqlGenerator)

I have created a test project to try it but when I create a new connection `return new NpgsqlConnection();`, it throw this exception to me:

```
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory'. Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config.
```

Follow the instruction found in the Npgsql official site, I use this app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql.EntityFramework"></provider>
    </providers>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionFactory, Npgsql" />
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Npgsql" />
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" support="FF" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Postgresql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

I don't understand why this exception is fired up. I have tried a lot of configuration but anyone works.

Comment: Did you try to add the dbproviderfactories configuration to the machine.config file? When I use edmgen, for example, it looks for the configuration in the machine.config file. How are you using your program? Can you post a sample? On a side note, would you like to contribute your code to Npgsql? This way a lot of Npgsql users could benefit from your code. Also, if it is not possible to contribute code, let me know more about your project so we can add a reference to it in our documentation.

Comment: I tried with the machine.conf but not works.

Comment: This is a SqlMigrationGenerator to enable entity framework to use manual migrations. I have tweaked my class and now it starts to work. Before, i was inheriting the SqlServerMigrationGenerator but now I Inherit the MigrationSqlGenerator and works better but isn't complete. I posted to nuget the release for Entity Framework 5 (https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.v5.PostgreSql/) but I have few problems to complete this version for EF6. It cloud be great contribute Npgsql with my code so Npgsql may response to all the features of ef. Thanks

Answer (score 19):

Solution Explorer

1. Right click over file .edmx
2. Open with..
3. Editor XML
4. Change ProviderManifestToken="XXXX" with 2008

Comment: Worked for me. I had 2012 and switched to 2008, which solved my issue. Thanks.

Comment: Be good to know the cause and why it's still not fixed. Not sure if this is a Telerik issue for me.

Comment: All I can think with changing from 2012 to 2008 is that maybe it has something to do with the SQL Server version. I'm using a 2008 R2 database, so maybe there's a bug or some issue where EF6 doesn't pick up the correct database version. Changing from 2012 to 2008 worked for me.

Comment: @Vincenzo Costa, it seems that this solution is only possible with database first approach and not code first. Is there any other way this can be achieved in code first approach.

Comment: @Cizap. I would not be wrong, but the .edmx file is also created with approach Code First

Answer (score 0):

For MVC application inside Global.asax in method Application_Start() at the end I put line:

Database.SetInitializer(null);

This solved same problem.

Comment: This fixed my issue with EF 5 (as we're still using EF v5 for some projects).

Answer (score 0):

Installing [Entity Framework 6 Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762) will solve your problem.

Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

delete the __MigrationHistory table if you are using code first and generating database using migration